# Error al momento de guardar datos VB.net

Tags: vb.net

estoy tratando de guardar datos en una base de datos desde visual basic, pero me salta un error y no logro comprender en donde se encuentra, en un principio el error era que no se podía cerrar la conexión, espero puedan ayudarme, les dejo mi código:

```
 Private Sub Registrar()
Dim Genero As String
Genero = IIf(rbxM.Checked, "M", If(rbxF.Checked, "F", ""))
Dim vsql As String
vsql = " EXEC _RegistrarCliente @cod_Cli ='" & txtCodigo.Text.Trim & "', @nom_Cli  ='" & txtNombre.Text.Trim & "', @ape_Cli ='"
vsql = vsql + txtApellido.Text.Trim & "', @direc_Cl ='" & txtDireccion.Text.Trim & "',@cod_Loc ='"
vsql = vsql + txtCL.Text.Trim & " ', @genero =" & Genero & ", @DNI ='" & txtDNI.Text.Trim & "', @RUC ='" & txtRUC.Text.Trim & "', @telf_Cli='" & txtTelefono.Text.Trim & "'"
cn.Open()    'abriendo conexión
Dim cmRegistrarCliente As New SqlCommand(vsql, cn)
Try
    cmRegistrarCliente.ExecuteNonQuery()     'Ejecutando orden SQL en el servidor de BD
    cn.Close()       'abriendo conexión
    MessageBox.Show("Registro ingresado....")
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error...", Err.Description)
End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: Mostra el error real... no lo que vos supones que decia el error. El codigo parece bien, asi que no vamos a poder ayudarte si no sabemos que error tenes....

Comment: Ha intentado usar el string que vsql contiene con un query directamente con el BD?  Puede ser un error en el query.

Answer (score 0):

Buen Día, checa al parecer es un error de interpretación de Strings ademas que no estas dando la instruccion update o insert into, puede ser que la forma en que tengas para insertarlo difiera de tu consulta sql ejemplo.

```
Dim Num As Integer
Num = DGTabla.CurrentCell.Value
consultam = ("UPDATE ""SQUEMA"".""TABLA"" SET ""U_SO1_02REIMPRESO"" ='Y'" & "WHERE ""DocEntry"" =" & Num)
```

En este caso anterior ya el registro existe en mi BD Y voy a actualizar un campo a 'Y' donde Num sea encontrado en mi Tabla. En este siguiente voya a agregar 1 dato.

```
INSERT INTO [OITM] ([CodeBars], [ItemName], [BinCode], [ItemCode], [Stock]) VALUES ('7501070981518', '***ESTECLIN 300MG 20 CAPS', '01GRAL-3-1-R2', 20018, 0);
```

Aquí la verdad en función de tu vb.net puede que necesites poner comillas dobles o cuádruples "" "" dependiendo el caso, solo con ' ' fechas, " " para strings o sin comillas numeros.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.